# Flames which are actually alive

Tags: science-based, biology

It can reproduce, it can die, it eats and consumes.
It burns all the time, it is incredibly sticky, kind of like benzin.
It is made of flames but has a shape, 4 legs and long whip tail.

Can such animal exist and if not what would it make it more probable?

Comment: Hi! When asking a science based question please provide more details and context. Is the environment Earth like? What kind of biology do you have in mind for this being? Are you asking about its evolution? Are the flames just on the surface of the animal or is the whole being made of flames?

Answer (score 3):

A being purely made of fire (plasma) would not be possible, you would lack the possibility for any persistence. So no memory, no problem solving, essentially everything that would make us consider it actually alive.

If however you can settle for something permanently on fire, say a slime for instance extruding gasoline or other flammable material. It's unlikely, but not a complete no. You'll have problems with energy, flames require a constant fuel source, and so it would be hard for such a lifeform to eat and produce the fuel fast enough.

So other than through some kind of magic, it's going to require some very large suspension of disbelief.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we put science aside for a while and use our imagination, it sure can.

**Some alien substance or object**

There was a leftover bonfire ( or some kind of forest on fire ) and then some unidentified object fell from the sky, when the object came into contact with fire, it suddenly gave it life.

Now the object is one with the fire and it made a strange looking fire shape with 4 legs and a long tail, leaving behind some fire trails where it walked.

The strange creature didn't know anything that was happening at first, but after some time it started "thinking" and realized that it could produce more and more fire anywhere it goes but these fires were not like him, these fires couldn't walk or think, they were only normal fires. It then started wondering why it was the only one with these abilities and suddenly realized that there was this kind of "rock" inside of him, looking like a heart, after examining it for a while, it tried putting fire on a bush next to him while touching this "rock" inside of him, and for his surprise, the burning bush was now also alive, he had just reproduced and made another strange looking fire creature.

**If you want to add science into it**

Let's say this rock is an alien material which is ultra-durable and won't stop burning at all, even if you try to throw water on it, that's why the creature could survive always burning. Also it has some alien DNA which would "infect" anything it comes in touch, such as fire.

**Well, that's the best I could think of.**